# 'Int' is not convertible to 'Range<Int>'

Tags: swift, type-conversion, xcode6

I've recently migrated from Xcode 6.0 to Xcode 6.1 and i've got compilation errors on some code which previously compiled fine.

Here is the line causing an error :

```
 self.possibleWidgetUnits[widgetSizes.Small.rawValue] = WidgetFormat(width:1.0, height:1.0)
```

The error is :

```
 'Int' is not convertible to 'Range<Int>'
```

Here is my variables declarations :

```
typealias WidgetFormat = (width:Int, height:Int)
var possibleWidgetUnits:[WidgetFormat]
```

What is wrong with these lines ?

**EDIT :**

```
enum widgetSizes : Int {
case Small = 0
case Medium = 1
case Large = 2
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `widgetSizes`?

Comment: @busina's answer seems to solve the problem

Comment: This is one of the many misleading error messages the Swift compiler produces.

Comment: And god knows there is a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem may come when you assign your WidgetFormat, you should try to remove the '.0' xcode may try to declare a Double and not an Int.

like this :

```
self.possibleWidgetUnits[widgetSizes.Small.rawValue] = WidgetFormat(width:1, height:1)
```

Xcode is not always right about the line's error and is not indicating the right origin of the problem.